# Scandir newest files in array with limit

Tags: php, arrays, scandir

I have made a PHP script to scan a directory, it lists all filenames in an array with a limit of 20. Now its displaying only the beginning of the array. So if there are 40 files, it displays only the first 0-20 but we need 20-40.. Can someone help me ? Thanks!!

```
<?php

$files = glob('data/*.{png}', GLOB_BRACE);
usort($files, 'filemtime_compare');

function filemtime_compare($a, $b)
{
    return filemtime($a) - filemtime($b);
}

$i = 0;
$show = 20;
foreach($files as $file)
{
    if($i == $show) {
         break;
    } else {
         ++$i;
    }
    $var .= $file . "\n";

}
$fp = fopen("data.txt", "wb");
fwrite($fp, $var);  
fclose($fp);
echo $var;

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/array_chunk) to split the $files array up in chunks of 20 files. Then use [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) to format the values in a chunk to a single string. Replace the foreach loop with this:

```
$show = 20;
$files = array_chunk($files, $show);
$page = 0; // page 0 is 0-19, page 1 is 20-39, etc.
$var = implode("\n", $files[$page]);
```

Edit: For the last 20 files you could use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice):

```
$files = array_slice($files, -20);
$var = implode("\n", $files);
```

Comment: Then use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice) to get the last 20 values: `$files = array_slice($files, -20);`. Updated the answer with that.

Comment: Thanks, this is not depended on how many files there are on the server ? This fluctuate sometimes there are 20 and sometimes there are 120 files on the server, but i allways need the newest 20 of them.

Comment: That doesn't matter. If there are less than 20 values in the array, all values are returned.